# javascript : calculate taxi cost based on 3 distance ranges

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

The problem is calculating the total cost to be paid to the taxi driver with the following rules:

- for the first hundred meters, the rental rate is 100 / meter.
- for the next hundred meters to the first 500 meters, the rental rate is 50 / meter.
- for 500 meters to the end, the rental rate is 10 / meter.

the unit of distance entered is kilo meters.

(It's the easy part to change the distance so don't bother.)

Since this is a problem from the pop quiz and I didn't study at all, I just came out with this solution

```
function counter(distance) {
  distance = distance * 1000;

  meter = 0;
  totalCost = 0;

  while (meter <= distance) {
    if (meter <= 100) {
      totalCost = 100;
    }
    if (meter > 100 && meter <= 500) {
      totalCost = totalCost + 50;
    }
    if (meter > 500) {
      totalCost = totalCost + 10;
    }

    meter = meter + 1;
  }

  return totalCost;
}
```

Which is so stupid because there are so many repetitions. Can you guys show me the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. In this case the question MAY be a better fit at codereview

Comment: @mplungjan thanks, I will definitely do as you say later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not too repetitive

```js
function counter(distance) {
  let totalCost = 0, dist = distance * 1000;
  for (let m = 1; m <= dist; m++) {
    if (m <= 100) totalCost += 100;
    else totalCost += (m <= 500) ? 50 : 10;
  }
  return totalCost;
}

console.log(1000*.001,counter(.001))
console.log(1000*.01,counter(.01))
console.log(1000*.1,counter(.1))
console.log(1000*.2,counter(.2))
console.log(1000*.5,counter(.5))
console.log(1000,counter(1))
```

Comment: Using for loop is not really necessary here 
you are running each condition for N*1000 times where N is input KM
we just need to check each condition only once
see my answer :)

Comment: Sure. However I do not expect a taxi to drive around the globe

Comment: You're right my way is very repetitive, yours is a better approach, I hope my grades in class don't go down

Answer (score 0):

You can just check one condition at a time and reduce problem for next condition as follows:

```js
function counter(distance) {
  distance = distance * 1000;
  let totalCost = 0;
  if (distance > 500) {
    totalCost += (distance - 500) * 10;
    distance = 500;
  }
  if (distance > 100) {
    totalCost += (distance - 100) * 50;
    distance = 100;
  }
  if(distance>0)
   totalCost += distance * 100;

  return totalCost;
}

console.log(counter(.1))
console.log(counter(.01))
```

Comment: @mplungjan yes thanks
missed that
it works now

its great how we can use inline snippets 
did not know that

Comment: I think `totalCost += (distance - 100) * 50; distance = 100;` is not correct. You need to set distance to distance-100

Comment: oh so you can run 3 if in the same time, I do not know that

Comment: @AlifIrhas yes you can 
and you should not use for loop when its not necessary

with for loop your code gets time complexity of O(n)
without loop it is constant complexity O(1)
which is always better

Answer (score 0):

```
var distance = 2
function counter(distance) {
  distance = distance * 1000;
  
  const p_r = [100,50,10]
  const d_r = [100,400, distance-500]
  
  var totalCost = 0
  
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    distance = distance - d_r[i]
    totalCost += d_r[i]*p_r[i]
    
    console.log(distance +" "+ totalCost)
}
  
  const t_cost = totalCost-9900 
  return "t cost: "+t_cost;
}

console.log(counter(distance))
```

Not too pretty, but it's short and it's definitely a way different approach..
It gives the same output btw..

Comment: yes, yours is very different. Most of all my classmates' answers look like those of Desi Mulga or mplungjan.

Comment: To be honest with you, all these other solutions are better then this one, but since you wanted something different, here ya go haha

Answer (score 0):

Hard coded but readble :)

```js
// Rules as functions
function calc_before100(dis){
  return dis * 100;
}
  
function calc_btw100and500(dis){
  first_100 = calc_before100(100)
  rest = dis - 100;
  rest_price = rest * 50;
  total = first_100 + rest_price;
  return total;
}
  
function calc_after500(dis){
  first_500 = calc_btw100and500(500);
  rest = dis - 500;
  rest_price = rest * 10;
  total = first_500 + rest_price;
  return total;
}

// Main function  
function taxi_price(dis) {
  price = 0
  
  if (dis <= 100) {
    price = calc_before100(dis);
  }
  if (dis > 100 && dis <= 500){
    price = calc_btw100and500(dis);
  }
  if (dis > 500){
    price = calc_after500(dis);
  }
  return price
}

// The distance unit is meter
p = taxi_price(150);
console.log(p);
```

Comment: yeah this code is very easy to read. thank you

Comment: I've simplified the code more, you can check it! 
but there is something I have to mention which is "in this case, loops are not necessary".